# model.addAttribute() For Each Loop

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm just starting to get my feet wet in Spring MVC. I'm consuming an external crypto currency API. I'm trying to use a for each loop to iterate over a JSON response to insert each value into the model using the addAttribute method. I'm only getting the last value though.

Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/Tables", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String test(Model model) throws IOException {
        ResponseEntity<coins[]> test = getRequest();
        for (coins i : test.getBody()) {
            model.addAttribute("coins", i);
        }
        return "Tables";
    }

    public ResponseEntity<coins[]> getRequest() throws IOException {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String apiUrl = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/list";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[]{MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}));
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
        ResponseEntity<coins[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(apiUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, coins[].class);
        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            return response;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        return response;
    }
```

Model:

```
    @JsonProperty("id")
    public String id;
    @JsonProperty("symbol")
    public String symbol;
    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;
```

View:

```
<tr th:each="coins : ${coins}">
     <td th:text="${coins.id}"></td>
     <td th:text="${coins.symbol}"></td>
     <td th:text="${coins.name}"></td>
     <td class="text-right">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-info btn-icon btn-sm like"><i class="tim-icons icon-heart-2"></i></a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-danger btn-icon btn-sm remove"><i class="tim-icons icon-simple-remove"></i></a>
     </td>
</tr>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qqfT.png)

Any Suggestions? Appreciate any help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I didn't need run a for each loop in the controller. I removed the loop and inserted test.getBody() using the addAttribute method into the model and it worked fine.